# Hide mobile browser chrome with javascript (working on iPhone but not Android)

Tags: javascript, android, mobile

Ive used the following javascript to hide the browser chrome for mobiles by scrolling down the page just enough that its out of view. It works fine for iPhone but does nothing on the first android ive tested with.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
            window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        }
```

Comment: What browser on Android have you tested? I have been having issues more often with the default browser on my Galaxy SII while Chrome, Firefox and Opera worked flawless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need to put more than 0 scroll. I think this will work.

```
window.scrollTo(0,1);
```